# How to implement a method declared in DLL on the client side in C++

Tags: c++, dll

I split my project into a dynamic library and it's client code.

In the library I have class ObjectModel.

object_model.h:

```
class ObjectModel {
     public:
         virtual ~ObjectModel();
         static ObjectModel& Get();

         /* Some other methods */
     protected:
         ObjectModel();
         ObjectModel( const ObjectModel& );
         ObjectModel& operator=( ObjectModel& );
};
```

I use method `ObjectModel::Get()` in the library and in the client code. I don't implement the method in the library because I need to get extended object and use it in library in another project.

On the client side:

```
#include <object_model.h>

class ExObjectModel : public ObjectModel {
}

ObjectModel& ObjectModel::Get() {
    static ExObjectModel m;
    return m;
}

int main() {
    ObjectModel &m = ObjectModel::Get();
    /* ... */
}
```

It works on Linux perfectly. But I can't compile DLL using MinGW because of error "undefined reference to ObjectModel::Get()". Is it possible to build DLL in a such way at all?

Comment: No. If you have `ObjectModel::Get()` implemented in another library, you need to link with that library.

Comment: @n.m. I understand it is off topic, but maybe you know another way to get the same functionality.

Comment: Have an `init` function in your DLL where you explicitly pass everything that it needs to function but cannot link against. In your case it looks like you need some kind of ObjectModel factory. See factory pattern. Create a factory in the main program and pass it as needed to the modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by @n.m's comment:

> No. If you have ObjectModel::Get() implemented in another library, you need to link with that library.

the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use ExObjectModel::Get() instead ObjectModel::Get(), because static functions can't work like virtual functions

Comment: In this case I can't use ExObjectMode inside in DLL because it calls ObjectModel::Get()