# How can I build a DLL that has a declaration but no definition of a function, in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I want to declare a function in a DLL and then define it in a client project so that the dll can call this function implemented in the client.

I started following a game engine tutorial series from the youtuber "The Cherno" and in one of the first episodes called [Entry Point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meARMOmTLgE&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dC-V-N3m0Go4deliWHPFwT&index=5), I created a file called `Entrypoint.h` with the content:

```
extern Hazel::Application* Hazel::CreateApplication();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Hazel::Application* app = Hazel::CreateApplication();
    app->Run();
    delete app;
}
```

This file belongs to the engine project which should be compiled into a DLL.

Then in a different project under the same solution I have the definition of the CreateApplication function.

```
Hazel::Application* Hazel::CreateApplication()
{
    return new Sandbox();
}
```

When I attempt to build these projects I get an `unresolved external symbol` linker error and after spending a long time researching I've found some answers on stackoverflow saying that this is not possible, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648295/how-to-implement-a-method-declared-in-dll-on-the-client-side-in-c), but if it isn't supposed to be possible then I don't understand why it works in the video and doesn't work with my code.

Comment: I won't watch the video for you, but are you sure you got the projects the right way around? normally a `main` function should go in a console application project

Comment: @user253751 yes, according to the video this `main` is in the dll project

Comment: It depends on your tools, but when the main executable, which has the exported function defined, is compiled, a .exp or .lib file should be produced that you must then include when linking the dll so that the name of the exe's entry point can be found by the linker when linking the dll.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm not sure I'm understanding. I have a project that builds into a dll, this project has the declaration. Then I have another project that builds into an exe, this project has the definition. What happens in the tutorial series is when he builds the projects, the dll project finds the definition in the exe project.

Comment: To comment on that I would need to watch the tutorial, which I am not prepared to do right now. Sorry.

Comment: What remains, though, is that when linking the dll, the linker needs to be able to build an import stub for the external function. To do that, it relies on a piece of data describing the function - its exported name, essentially - that the compiler generated when the exe was linked. This information usually gets emitted to a .exp or .lib file.

Comment: *BTW*: there are some bad practices in that movie.

Comment: @CristiFati can you elaborate on what these bad practices are, as one of the reasons why I'm making this game engine is to get better at c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out why it wasn't working.

When I created one of the header files in the engine I accidentaly added it as a .cpp file and then changed the extension to .h, apparently this broke the program somehow. I fixed the error by deleting the header file and creating it again.

Only managed to find this out by remaking the project following the video and then comparing the settings files of both projects to find what was different between the two.